# Is there a way to provide a toast message on an android wear device?

Tags: android, wear-os, toast, android-toast

I am looking to a toast or a message of some sorts in my wear app. I'm not sure of any way to do this. Has anyone came across this?

Comment: Flagged as off-topic > asking for off-site resource. A complete answer to your question cannot be solved in this Q&A format. You do not have an isolated issue, but rather would like a tutorial on doing XYZ. I suggest doing some additional research.

Comment: Clearly not off topic

Answer (score 2):

Implententing a toast for Android wear devices works the same way you would have a toast on any android device